# Summation of all possible combinations

Tags: combinatorics

I need to get the summation of all triplets produced by (nCr) where r = 3. I've written a program that does this but it takes too long when n is very big.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=r}^{M} {n \choose r}= {{M+1} \choose {r+1}}$$

Comment: @ianosaur: It's any natural number you want.